# Getting 'offsetwidth' error when trying to display google maps

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3

I'm getting this error when trying to display Google Maps on my page.
"JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'offsetWidth' of undefined or null reference"

Its coming from the Javascript function initialize() from the line var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas")

```
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoom: 8
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Here is my html

```
<div id="map-canvas">
   <h2>hello</h2>
</div>
```

and here is my css

```
#map-canvas {
position: fixed;
top: 41px;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 40%;
height: 100%;
background-color: pink;
/*border: 3px solid black;*/
}
```

Comment: I got map displayed without problem. This error typically shows up when div id is different from string provided in `getElementById()`. Which browser do you have?

Comment: I got it. I had to use Chrome. Its still broken in IE. Does anyone know why?

Comment: What did you have to do in Chrome?  Can you provide a fiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't able to reproduce the reported error, however the map in your code (as posted) doesn't have a size.  Add this to your css to give the parents of the map-canvas div a size:

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DBVnn/)